# How to get a clean Ambient Occlusion map with Cycles with low samples?

Tags: compositing-nodes, texture-baking

I want to get a clean ambient occlusion without having to increase the samples, is there a way to hide the noise and maybe to fake Anti-Aliasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a normal map to blur the images without touching the edges to keep sharp details.

For that use a bilateral blur attach your ambient occlusion map and the normal map in the slot Determinator. You can play with the settings, i suggest you to lower the "Sigma" setting which is too high by default by something like 1.
You can also apply a small blur at the normal map to avoid getting edges too aliased and be closer to an anti-aliasing filter.

[image]